# How to make QInputDialog box modal less?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using multiple QInput Dialog boxes in my UI, using the syntax like

```
QString s = QInputDialog::getText(this,"Sleep Command ",
    "Enter the number of seconds" );
```

but when ever these Input dialog boxes pops up, the mainwindow becomes unresponsive, so how do i make all the QInputDialog boxes "modal less " and the mainwindow always stays responsive ??

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You probably don't want this. It's not good UX: having an extra window pop up to just enter something will easily cause it to get lost. You should integrate these prompts somehow within your main window, and make them dismissable. The `QInputDialog` is a bad crutch: it's bad when it's application modal, and it's even worse when it's not modal. It's best forgotten about.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica , yes , Agreed , but do you have any other suggestions or example, lets say i have 2 QListwidgets, A and B, Each item of A has 3 properties , when i click on 1 item of A, 3 properties of A are displayed in B , can i change these individual properties somehow ?

Comment: Of course. Lists are editable! You just need to set the items to be editable, and the view as well.

Comment: oh okay, Thanks, But can i do it this way, In Liswidget A first item `<name ="James", surname ="Madison", age ="22">`is single-clicked and when it is single clicked , 3 items appear in Listwidget B `name = James` ,`surname =Madison` , `age = 22` , and i make listwidget B editable , and i change 3rd item of list -B , that is "age = 40", now how do i manipulate this into the previously first selected item in LIst A. , i know i can change strings and append and stuff but how do i acess that first selected item

Comment: Something like this  ?? `void Mainwindow::on_List-B_itemEdited()
{
QString value = item->gettext();

if(value.contains(digit))
{

ui->List-A->selectedItem("<name ="James", surname ="Madison", age =" + value);
}

}`

Answer (score 1):

> so how do i make all the QInputDialog boxes "modal less "

reading the doc here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#details

you will find that using the static methods involves the fact that the dialogs are invoked "modal",

> The dialog's parent is parent. **The dialog will be modal** and uses
>   the specified widget flags.

so **no**, you can't use the method and don't block the main window until the user quits the dialog, BUT you can (imho is a bad idea) declare your own instance of a Dialog and [show](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show) it instead of execute it.